# UISwipeGestrureRecognizer not recogising swipe down - swift

Tags: xcode, swift

All I have an UIImage in an UIView and I  have added an UISwipeGestureRecogniser in both IB and in code. Code is like this :

```
  EventImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRec)
  EventImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
  swipeRec.addTarget(self, action: "swipedView")
```

It will read a 'right' swipe fine, but I want to control a down swipe. 
The UImage is in an View and the View is a part of a scrollview. So I have switched off DirectionLock and Bounces. So the UIView cannot be pushed down from the NAV BAR. And it still doesn't recognise a swipe down.

Any ideas ?

In IB I have created the recogniser by dragging an 'Swipe Gesture Recogniser' on to the image I want to be able to use the gesture.

Then if i select the 'Gesture in IB' I can set which way the gesture goes, and I select down like this :

[image]

Then I set an func in swift and it does not recogise down but when I change it to right i works fine.. I  have checked the idea by using breakpoints and the breakpoint triggers on Right swipe (and left) but going down doesn't work. 
I think it could be because I am in a scroll view.

I have added :

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

As I thought this may help.

Hope this is clearer.

Comment: Show us how you've implemented the gesturerecognizer

Comment: I have made it more detailed, thanks Christian.

Answer (score 0):

A `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` can only recognise swipes in one direction.

That direction is set in the `direction` property of it.

If you want to swipe right or down then you will need two gesture recognisers. One for the right swipe and one for the down swipe.

```
recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
```

Also, it help to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html). All of this info is directly from there.

Comment: yes i know, and in IB you can set which way.. So I set it to the right and it works, I set it to the bottom and it doesn't trigger.